# My app is on 200% zoom

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

When I run my game it's like the zoom was on 200%. I dont know what to do to make it normal.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var scene: GameScene!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // CONFIGURE THE VIEW 
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

        // create and configure the scene
        scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        // Present the scene
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
```

p.s: I already checked and it's not in the simulator's settings

Comment: What is the desired results here?  It seems we do not have enough info to actually answer this.  From the looks of this, if you have autolayout setup,  your initial view setup will be 600x600.  So your scene will be 600x600 in size.  Then auto layout will take place, and resize your screen to (Lets say iphone 4s) 320x480.  So the scene is going to scale the 600x600 down to this size, while still maintaining a scene area of 600x600

Comment: By chance is the device rotated in landscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your scene looks zoomed is explained by the scaling factor (`AspectFill`). You'll likely want to use either `Fill` or `ResizeFill`.

With `SKSceneScaleMode` you have four options:

### Fill

> Each axis of the scene is scaled independently so that each axis in
>   the scene exactly maps to the length of that axis in the view.

### AspectFill

> The scaling factor of each dimension is calculated and the larger of
>   the two is chosen. Each axis of the scene is scaled by the same
>   scaling factor. This guarantees that the entire area of the view is
>   filled but may cause parts of the scene to be cropped.

### AspectFit

> The scaling factor of each dimension is calculated and the smaller of
>   the two is chosen. Each axis of the scene is scaled by the same
>   scaling factor. This guarantees that the entire scene is visible but
>   may require letterboxing in the view.

### ResizeFill

> The scene is not scaled to match the view. Instead, the scene is
>   automatically resized so that its dimensions always match those of the
>   view.

---

<sub>Available in iOS 7.0 and later.</sub>

↳ https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SKSceneScaleMode

Comment: @AlexandreDiPisa: Show which methods you tried and how it was used.

Comment: `class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var scene: GameScene!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    
    // CONFIGURE THE VIEW 
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false
        
    // create and configure the scene
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .Fill
    
    // Present the scene
    skView.presentScene(scene)
        
    }`

Comment: @I'L"I: `scene.scaleMode = .Fill`

Comment: No matter what option you pick of those,  some scaling is going to happen, causing a zoom effect